# Delphi Borland database engine 64 bit compilation

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, bde

I have my application already running in Delphi XE2 and compiled for 32 bit.
Database components used are BDE Borland database engine.

Now, I am planning to compile my application on 64 bit platform in XE2 only.
But BDE is not available in 64 bit, components are disabled.

When I try to compile the application I get error message
'[DCC Error] BDE.pas(7011): E1026 File not found: 'IDPAS32.OBJ'

Can you please help me out?

Comment: There's no "BDE 64 bit", you must have installed something else.

Comment: @Sertac:  Ok..I will check
which components will be best to replace BDE? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I can't answer what's best, at the very least I don't know all.

Comment: FireDAC is distributed (as add-on) for Delphi, but from XE3 and up, AFAIR. Consider using UniDAC. Or use Open Source alternatives, like https://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/ or http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_126 - the later has a TQuery class, code compatible with BDE's TQuery. But you will have to replace all components in your project... consider using a search/replace automated tool for this, directly in the .dfm and .pas files...

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez:   Thank you very much. I tried using DBExpress. I will check with UniDAC.

Comment: DBExpress has been somewhat "replaced" by FireDac - so I would not go into this direction, since future support will be very limited. Take an active project! An Open Source makes it even safer, since even if the company behind collapses, maintainability can still be done by the users!

Comment: why two negative votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 64 bit version of BDE. You will need to remain on BDE with a 32 bit program or replace BDE.